# Jquery - slideleft, code not working?

Tags: jquery, effects

Title is descriptive, what is wrong with this code and why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft').mouseenter(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
      $lefty.animate({ 
        left: "-2000px"
             }, 500 );
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="slideleft" class="slide"> 

  <div class="inner">Animate this element's left style property</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(this).next()` should be grabbing the next sibling of `div#slideleft` but it appears you actually want `div.inner` to be sliding right?  If you change `$(this).next()` to `$(this).children('.inner')` it should work.